# C++ compiler issue: 3>cl : Command line error D8016: '/clr' and '/arch:SSE2' command-line options are incompatible

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, linker-errors

i've been messing around with C++ for the first time, and have been following a tutorial on how to program a simple synth.  Ive been fine up till now, but after continuously getting this error and failing to find a solution (yes I've looked here for similar posts and none of the solutions have worked)  Can anyone explain what this error means and how I can figure it out? Thanks!

MORE INFORMATION:

I worked until i got this particular part of the tutorial, having no errors completing everything up to this section.

http://www.martin-finke.de/blog/articles/audio-plugins-011-envelopes/

Comment: The source download contains a project file for visual studio. Did you use that?

Comment: I tried to load the Visual Studio project in VS2010 but it appears require folders and some files that are not in the sources so all of the projects in the solution failed to load.

Comment: I downloaded both and they didnt work which made me believe it was not an issue with my code, but rather with visual studio.  how do I remove /arch:SSE2 from the settings?

Comment: I also think the project is not .NET so the /arch:SSE2 is not the problem but using /clr is.

Answer (score 0):

I would disregard drescherjm's suggestion, instead changing the project type.

You have set the project up to use the .NET run-time. (/clr = /commonLanguageRuntime). Given that the source archive also includes a MACOSX folder and more particularly, a CBP file (Code::Blocks project) that doesn't use the MS compiler (so therefore, **can't** be built using clr), it's entirely safe to say this is not intended to be a c++/clr program, but is instead is intended to be a plain c++ one.

Just re-create the project and copy your existing files into the new folder, re-add them to the project and voila!